# How difficult would it be to incorporate AssemblyScript?

Tags: wasm, javascript, typescript

It would be awesome to see support for [AssemblyScript](https://github.com/dfinity/assemblyscript) (which compiles typescript to wasm).

So how can we do this?

The database interface seems like the main headache. Boost seems to be way too complex to implement, so perhaps this should start with something like: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosiolib/datastream.hpp. But how would abi integration work in this case?

Secondly there are quite a few other [library functions](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/master/contracts/eosiolib) that should get implemented.

It would be great if someone could provide me with a complete list of requirements for just the barebone, core libraries that would have to be integrated!

If these are not that long, what are we waiting for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is being documented [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/3204).

TL/DR: Getting the most basic functionality to work is very easy. You only need to export an apply(uint64, uint64, uint64) function in webassembly, which can be easily done in AssemblyScript.